# extract char from string

Tags: c++, string

Having a string `HelloHello` how can I extract (i.e. omit) the first char, to have `elloHello`?

I've thought of `.at()` and `string[n]` but they return the value and don't delete it from the string

Comment: What type is your string?  char* or std::string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int,char**)
{
  std::string x = "HelloHello";
  x.erase(x.begin());
  std::cout << x << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

prints

```
elloHello
```

Comment: what is this operator called :: ?

Comment: @SaraKholusi: That is the scope resolution operator.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)

```
std::string str ("HelloHello");

str.erase (0,1);  // Removes 1 characters starting at 0.

// ... or

str.erase(str.begin());
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use substring. The first parameter indicates the start position. The second parameter `string::npos` means you want the new string to contain all characters from the specified start position until the end of the string.

```
std::string shorterString = hellohello.substr(1,  std::string::npos);
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Answer (score 2):

Try using substr()

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/